# SQL query- I need to fill the null values to their previous row values. what query to i use?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

So i have a table with the columns:

OccupancyID | Calendar_date | DateofTransactions | RentDue

as shown in the image. I want to replace the null values in columns `DateOfTransactions` and `RentDue` to the previous row values of that  column.

To show something like this:

[image]

Help me with a MS sql query

Comment: Changing date formats and fonts between the two images is not helpful. No idea where the date June 15 comes from nor why it appears FOR EVERY ROW. You have also removed RentDue from your output. Perhaps LAG or LEAD is useful here but it is difficult to know what you desire. Seems you should also consider using DATE for your columns rather than DATETIME.

Comment: You should add sample data. Picture does not help anyone to understand your problem.

Comment: *Consumable* Sample data (that means as DDL and DML statements, or at least as well formatted tabular `text`) as well as your attempts will help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in two steps.  The idea is to assign a group by counting the non-`NULL` values in a column.  Then you can shmear the values within the group.

Assuming the `NULL`s match in the two columns (as in the sample data):

```
select t.*,
       max(dateoftransaction) over (partition by occupancyid, grp) as imputed_dateoftransaction,
       max(rentdue) over (partition by occupancyid, grp) as imputed_rentdue
from (select t.*,
             count(dateoftransaction) over (partition by occupancyid order by calendardate) as grp
      from t
     ) t
```